# Record audio on mobile through web

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, mobile-website, voice-recording

I would like to be able to record audio on mobile phones by having the user trigger the recording through a button press on a web page. Based on what I've read, audio recording is supported (kind of) in HTML 5, but not all browsers implement it yet. Many similiar questions are 6-15 months old and it seems like support for audio recording is moving forward quite rapidly.

So what I wonder is, can this be done today or in the next 3-6 months, or do I have to create native apps for the various phones?

Answer (score 0):

Probably Cordova-like framework is a way to go for you. You'll be able to create html app and Cordova build will create native packages for all platforms for you.

Cordova (PhoneGap) home

http://phonegap.com/

Special audio recording shim

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html

Comment: or the Rho Mobile platform.